# Magento 2 get Website names dropdown on any phtml

Tags: magento2, phtml, websites, switcher

How can we get the Website names dropdown (Website Switcher) in any phtml (Ex : header.phtml) in Magento 2

Comment: https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-website-collection-programmatically-in-magento-2/ is used for getting collection of website name.

Answer (score 5):

To get the list of all websites, you indeed need to use the storeManager, which is a native variable of every block extending \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template:.

You can access this easily by creating a custom block inside any custom module. The block code goes here..

```
<?php
namespace Magento2\Custom\Block;
class WebsiteSwitcher extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template{
    public function getWebsites() {
        return $this->_storeManager->getWebsites();
    }
    public function getCurrentWebsiteId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getId();
    }

}
```

After this call this inside your layout using a phtml file. Create a phtml file inside your theme folder. Path will be similar to

```
magento2\app\design\frontend\CompanyName\ThemeName\Magento_Store\templates\switch\websites.phtml
```

Put contents like this..

```
<?php
$websites = $block->getWebsites();
$websiteId = $block->getCurrentWebsiteId();
?>
<?php if (count($block->getWebsites()) > 1): ?>
<div class="switcher website switcher-website" id="switcher-website">
<strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?php echo __('Select Website') ?></span></strong>

<div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
    <?php foreach ($websites as $website): ?>
    <?php if ($websiteId == $website->getId()): ?>
    <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
         role="button"
         tabindex="0"
         data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
         data-toggle="dropdown"
         data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
         id="switcher-website-trigger">
        <strong>
            <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?></span>
        </strong>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown" data-target="dropdown">
    <?php foreach ($websites as $website): ?>
    <?php if (!($websiteId == $website->getId())): ?>
        <li class="switcher-option">
            <a href='<?php echo $website->getDefaultStore()->getCurrentUrl() ?>'>
                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

After adding the phtml file then call the block and phtml inside your layout. The path will be `magento2\app\design\frontend\CompanyName\ThemeName\Magento_Theme\layout\default.xml`

Add this inside `<referenceContainer name="header.panel">` for getting the dropdown in global header.

```
<block class="Magento2\Custom\Block\Websiteswitcher" name="website_switcher" as="website_switcher"  template="Magento_Store::switch/websites.phtml"  before="store_language"/>
```

class name is nothing but your custom block's class name.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 already provide functionality to Store Switcher.
For that you need to look into this file.

```
Magento\Store\Block\Switcher
```

and it relavent template file is here

```
Magento\Store\view\frontend\templates\switch\stores.phtml
```

Answer (score 2):

Also,you can use the websites name using Object Manager.

```
//Get Object Manager Instance
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$websiteGroups = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getGroups();

foreach ($websiteGroups as $group) {
 $group->getName();
}
```

**Note:** *direct use of Object Manager is not practice.*

### best Practice

Also better idea is that at your phtml's  block class use `Magento\Store\Model\Group;`  then add a function

```
use Magento\Store\Model\Group;

public function getWebsitesList(){
 return $websiteGroups = $this->_storeManager->getWebsite()->getGroups();
}
```

And call this function at phtml

```
$websiteGroups = $block->getWebsitesList();
foreach ($websiteGroups as $group) {
 $group->getName();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I made it, just changed the code of Asheem Patro because there were some mistakes on it:

```
 <?php
 $websites = $block->getWebsites();
 $websiteid = $block->getCurrentWebsiteId();
 ?>
 <?php if (count($block->getWebsites())>1): ?>
<div class="switcher website switcher-website" id="switcher-website">
  <strong class="label switcher-label"><span><?php echo __('Select Website') ?></span></strong>
  <div class="actions dropdown options switcher-options">
    <?php foreach ($websites as $website): ?>
      <?php if ($websiteid == $website->getId()): ?>
        <div class="action toggle switcher-trigger"
        role="button"
        tabindex="0"
        data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
        data-toggle="dropdown"
        data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
        id="switcher-website-trigger">
        <strong>
        <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?></span>
        </strong>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <ul class="dropdown switcher-dropdown" data-target="dropdown">
      <?php foreach ($websites as $website): ?>
        <?php if (!($websiteid == $website->getId())): ?>
          <li class="switcher-option">
            <a href='<?php echo $website->getDefaultStore()->getCurrentUrl() ?>'>
              <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($website->getName()) ?>
            </a>
          </li>
        <?php endif; ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get website collection website related data using programmatical way by `Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\CollectionFactory` Website collection,

Refer blog, [Get Website Name and other information programatically](https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-get-website-collection-programmatically-in-magento-2/)

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Website\CollectionFactory $websiteCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_websiteCollectionFactory = $websiteCollectionFactory
    }

     /**
     * Retrieve websites collection of system
     *
     * @return Website Collection
     */
    public function getWebsiteCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->_websiteCollectionFactory->create();
        return $collection;
    }
```